# Compiler sometimes can't find generated navigation files

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

This is a pretty bizarre one.

Occasionally, after some arbitrary change has been made to the nav graph XML, the build fails because it can't find two particular functions (nav directions) that should have been generated.

The error is like this:

```
main/java/com/project/upsell/UpsellFragment.kt: (99, 82): Unresolved reference: toMainFragment
main/java/com/project/upsell/UpsellVM: (35, 53): Unresolved reference: toSuccessFrag
```

I can "fix" it by renaming the functions, but the next time XML gets touched, the error recurs and the same "fix" is repeated. The same issue occurs in my environment, my teammate's environment and our Jenkins pipeline. Sometimes it builds fine locally but breaks in Jenkins.

The only clue I can offer is that it started happening shortly after bringing Compose into the project.

Some build info:

```
ext {
    dagger_version = '2.28.3'
    nav_version = '2.3.5'
    fragment_version = '1.3.6'
    coroutine_version = '1.5.0'
    compose_version = '1.0.1'
}
```

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.10"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.5" 
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:1.5.10"
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.0'
    }
```

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: "kotlin-kapt"
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
apply plugin: 'kotlinx-serialization'
```

```
 kotlinOptions {
        useIR = true
        freeCompilerArgs += ['-Xuse-experimental=kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi',
                             '-Xuse-experimental=kotlinx.coroutines.FlowPreview',
                             '-Xopt-in=androidx.paging.ExperimentalPagingApi',
                             '-Xuse-experimental=kotlinx.coroutines.InternalCoroutinesApi',
                             '-Xopt-in=kotlin.ExperimentalStdlibApi']
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerVersion = "1.5.10"
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.0.0-rc01'
    }
```

```
   buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
        compose = true
    }
```

Any insight would be appreciated

Comment: The next time this happens, try going to Build > Clean Project and then Build > Rebuild Project and seeing if that fixes the issue. Changing the xml file can sometimes cause issues with code generation

Comment: Sadly that isn't a solution for this one

Answer (score 0):

Fist try Invalidate Cache and Restart.

If that doesn't work, Add package name in your manifest, if it's missing.

```
<manifest 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.package"
...
```